# ipywidgets, how to change slider's value display precision

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, ipywidgets

In jupyter,I have the following code to create a slider control for my variable r using ipywidgets.

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

r = 0.9992
def sl(r=0.9992):
    global ar
    ar = r

interact(sl, r=(0.999, 1, 0.0001))
```

It works but the problem is that the display of slider value is rounded to 2 decimal. As a result, the display always show 1.00.

[image]

Is there any way to display its actual value?

Answer (score 8):

Since the version 6.x of ipywidgets, `FloatSlider` contains `readout_format` attribute. Just set it to your desired precision, e.g. like this:

```python
widgets.FloatSlider(value=7.5, min=0, max=10.0, 
                    step=0.001, readout_format='.3f')
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/259)

Values are somehow computed on the way and maybe it's not possible to do it with FloatSlider. You can use SelectionSlider instead of Float.

```
my_values = [i / 1000 for i in range(10)]  # [0.001, 0.002, ...] Or use numpy to list

SelectionSlider(options=[("%g"%i,i) for i in my_values])
```

[image: Widget]

Answer (score -1):

Your code works if your function has a `return` value and it displays the precision you want to see in a label below  (as in image)

mostly from info @ http://test-widgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html

```
from ipywidgets import *
from IPython.display import display

def SL(r):
    return r

interact(SL,r=widgets.FloatSlider(value=0.9992,min=0.9990,max=1.0000,step=0.0001,description='Precision:',))
```

[the slider result with precision displayed below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvTym.jpg)